# Accessing an image outside the drawable folder in android

Tags: android, image

I have been using the images in the drawable folder to display images In my Android Application. Is there any way to access the images outside the drawable folder? Or images in another through a url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [BitmapFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html) class has different methods allowing you to decode resources from streams or files, you should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Just use PackageManager:**

```
  getDrawable (String packageName, int resid, ApplicationInfo appInfo)
```